# C++ memory - Do primitive-typed variables created with 'new' need to be deleted?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, memory-management, allocation

I'm kind of new when it comes to memory management in C++. I read that if you create a class with the `new` keyword you must `delete` the object to free its memory. I also read that primitive types, such as `int`, `char` and `bool`, are created on the stack, which means they get deleted when they go out of scopes.

But what about primitive types created with the `new` keyword? Do I need to explicitly call `delete`? Are these created on the heap like classes? Or since they are primitive do they still get created on the stack?

I am asking because I am allocating a `LPTSTR` using the new keyword, but I am worried that if I do not call `delete` that the memory will never be freed. Here is my code with the bare question in the comments:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>

#ifdef _UNICODE
    typedef std::wstring Str;
#else // ANSI
    typedef std::string Str;
#endif

Str GetWndStr(HWND hwnd) {
    const int length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);

    if (length != 0) {
        LPTSTR buffer = new TCHAR[length + 1]; // Allocation of string
        GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, length + 1);
        Str text(buffer);

        delete buffer; // <--- Is this line necessary?
        return text;
    } else {
        return _T("");
    }
}
```

Do I need to call `delete`? Awhile back, I tried using `GlobalAlloc()` and `GlobalFree()`, but during runtime I got an error saying something about illegally modifying the stack, I do not have an exact error message as this was awhile ago. Also, in addition to your answer, if you would like to give me resources you found helpful to learn more about C++ memory management, that would be nice.

Comment: If you are using Java/C# then no need of `delete` for any type. :)

Comment: Classes are also created on the stack. In this regard primitive types and classes are no different. If you new it, it's on the heap, if you don't it's on the stack (usually). However classes may have internals, so the class itself could be on the stack, but some internal memory it's using could be on the heap.

Comment: " also read that primitive types, such as int, char and bool, are created on the stack" - either you were lied to, or you misunderstood what you read. Automatic variables are created on the stack (this isn't guaranteed, it's an implementation detail), and destroyed when out of scope (this is guaranteed). *Typically*, there is no need for dynamically-allocated objects of primitive type, you use automatic variables for those types. But anyway, the thing you're allocating doesn't have primitive type, it's an array. Of `TCHAR`, which is a primitive type.

Comment: Besides, `std::string` isnt a primitive type

Comment: @Evgeni Yes, but `LPTSTR` and `TCHAR` are. Which is what is being allocated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array is allocated with `new[]` and therefore must be deleted with `delete[]` (*not* `delete`).

Your explicit dynamic allocation is also unnecessary:

```
Str text(length+1, 0);
GetWindowText(hwnd, &text[0], length + 1);
text.resize(length); // remove NUL terminator
return text;
```

In C++03 there's some justification needed, whether `string` and `wstring` actually allocate contiguous memory, suitable for passing as a buffer. It's not guaranteed by the C++03 standard, but it is in fact true in MSVC++. If you don't want to rely on that fact, then it *is* guaranteed for vector, so you can use that for the buffer:

```
std::vector<TCHAR> buffer(length+1);
GetWindowText(hwnd, &buffer[0], length + 1);
return Str(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);
```

It is pretty rare to directly use `new[]` in C++. In both cases, my `vector` or `string` buffer is an automatic variable, so I don't have to do anything special to make sure that it is destroyed correctly when its scope ends.

Comment: +1 for std::vector use. Offers same features as the `scoped_array` without the additional dependency.

Comment: +1 For vector and string usage example. And explanation of vectors contiguous memory.

Answer (score 8):

For every `new` there must be a `delete` and for every `new[]` there must be a `delete[]`. Notice that the memory allocated with `new[]` must be deleted with `delete[]`, which is not the case in the posted code.

A smart pointer can be used, [`boost::scoped_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) for example, which will perform the `delete[]` in its destructor (or `reset()` function). This is particularly useful if exceptions can be thrown after the call to `new[]`:

```
boost::scoped_array<TCHAR> buffer(new TCHAR[length + 1]);
GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer.get(), length + 1);
Str text(buffer.get()); // buffer will be deleted at end of scope.
```

Comment: +1 for in-depth explanation and example of smart pointer usage. So are you saying since I use `new TCHAR[length + 1]`, that I need to use `delete[]`?

Comment: @BrandonMiller, yes. If `new[]` then `delete[]`.

Answer (score 2):

YES (unless you use smart pointers or similar to delete it for you)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the rule is very simple. Everything you allocate with `new` needs to be deallocated with `delete`; and everything allocated with `new[]` needs to be deallocated with `delete[]`.

To reduce the chances of error, it's best to use containers, smart pointers or other [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)-style objects to manage dynamic resources, rather than remembering to use `delete` yourself.

Comment: To add to the rules, anything that is constructed with `placement-new` must have its destructor explicitally called in code, if it has a destructor.  `Placement-new` allows you to construct something inside of an existing piece of memory instead of allocating a new memory block, like `new` and `new[]` do.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, no matter what type was allocated. It still have memory space.